# Suggested Lock for a sample case

Tags: java, multithreading

2 threads claim 2 reusable instances from a GenericObjectPool and start working on following dataset resp -

```
Thread 1 [ Rec1, Rec1, Rec2 ]

Thread 2 [ Rec1, Rec3, Rec2 ]

Thread 3 [ Rec3 ]
```

these records have to be looked up first, If not found then only inserted in a set of tables.So, in thread1 , **Rec1** twice occurence is handled safely as it runs sequentially.
But, Since there is contention across instances as Thread2 on second instance from Pool has also **Rec1** .Similarly Rec2 , Rec3  is also repeated.. So, I made lock to be static final..

And class itself looks like this -

```
Method1
--------
loop on all records
check condition1 
If Meets
lock obj
Recheck condition1
if meets
INSERT1
release lock
end loop
```

And ..

```
Method 2
---------
loop on all records
check condition2 
If Meets
lock obj
Recheck condition2
if meets
INSERT2
release lock
end loop
```

Suggestion on "obj" lock ? Making it static final will solve it but makes the program almost sequential due to extensive use of class level locking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont hold the lock while youre performing the operation. use synchronize calls only to arbitrate who gets to work on what record, do the operation not inside a synchronized block, and signal when youre done.

so (in java):

```
private final static Object LOCK = new Object();
private final static Set<Integer> busyRecords = new HashSet<Integer>();

public static void waitToWorkOn(int recordNum) {
   synchronized(LOCK) {
      while (busyRecords.contains(recordNum)) {
         LOCK.wait(); //go to sleep
      }
      busyRecords.add(recordNum); //ours now
   }
}

public static void doneWith(int recordNum) {
   synchronized(LOCK) {
      busyRecords.remove(recordNum);
      LOCK.notifyAll(); //wake sleepers up
   }
}
```

any code that uses this must use try-finally to make sure the release signal is sent:

```
waitToWorkOn(recordNum);
try {
   //do something to record
} finally {
   doneWith(recordNum);
}
```

Comment: radai, Since these threads work on different instances of the Class and busyRecords is a member variable, I think I need to make scope of busyRecords to be static as well so that all instances running could see busy entries ?

Comment: @fortm - the set shold have been static as well, my mistake. i'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead of your own locking mechanism. It's [Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/michael/PODC96.html)

If I understand you problem right you'd need two difference queues for method1 and method2 respectively. Also step called `loop on all records` will be defined as something like `get element from queue or wait`